# Too many open files warning from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Getting the below warning messages continuously. Not sure what should be done. Saw some of the relevant posts asking to increase the number of file descriptors.

How to do the same?

Even if I increase now, Will I encounter the same issue on addition of new indices. 
(presently working with around 400 indices, 6 shards and 1 replica). The number of indices tend to grow more.

```
[03:58:24,165][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [node1] received shard failed for [index9][2], node[node_hash3], [P], s[INITIALIZING], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[index9][2] failed recovery]; nested: EngineCreationFailureException[[index9][2] failed to open reader on writer]; nested: FileNotFoundException[/data/elasticsearch/whatever/nodes/0/indices/index9/2/index/segments_1 (Too many open files)]; ]] 
[03:58:24,166][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [node1] received shard failed for [index15][0], node[node_hash2], [P], s[INITIALIZING], reason [Failed to create shard, message [IndexShardCreationException[[index15][0] failed to create shard]; nested: IOException[directory '/data/elasticsearch/whatever/nodes/0/indices/index15/0/index' exists and is a directory, but cannot be listed: list() returned null]; ]] 
[03:58:24,195][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [node1] received shard failed for [index16][3], node[node_hash3], [P], s[INITIALIZING], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[index16][3] failed recovery]; nested: EngineCreationFailureException[[index16][3] failed to open reader on writer]; nested: FileNotFoundException[/data/elasticsearch/whatever/nodes/0/indices/index16/3/index/segments_1 (Too many open files)]; ]] 
[03:58:24,196][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [node1] received shard failed for [index17][0], node[node_hash3], [P], s[INITIALIZING], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[index17][0] failed recovery]; nested: EngineCreationFailureException[[index17][0] failed to open reader on writer]; nested: FileNotFoundException[/data/elasticsearch/whatever/nodes/0/indices/index17/0/index/segments_1 (Too many open files)]; ]] 
[03:58:24,198][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [node1] received shard failed for [index21][4], node[node_hash3], [P], s[INITIALIZING], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[index21][4] failed recovery]; nested: EngineCreationFailureException[[index21][4] failed to create engine]; nested: LockReleaseFailedException[Cannot forcefully unlock a NativeFSLock which is held by another indexer component: /data/elasticsearch/whatever/nodes/0/indices/index21/4/index/write.lock]; ]]
```

Output of nodes api

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes?os=true&process=true&pretty=true'

{ 
  "ok" : true, 
  "cluster_name" : "whatever", 
  "nodes" : { 
    "node_hash1" : { 
      "name" : "node1", 
      "transport_address" : "transportip1", 
      "hostname" : "myhostip1", 
      "version" : "0.20.4", 
      "http_address" : "httpip1", 
      "attributes" : { 
        "data" : "false", 
        "master" : "true" 
      }, 
      "os" : { 
        "refresh_interval" : 1000, 
        "available_processors" : 8, 
        "cpu" : { 
          "vendor" : "Intel", 
          "model" : "Xeon", 
          "mhz" : 2133, 
          "total_cores" : 8, 
          "total_sockets" : 8, 
          "cores_per_socket" : 16, 
          "cache_size" : "4kb", 
          "cache_size_in_bytes" : 4096 
        }, 
        "mem" : { 
          "total" : "7gb", 
          "total_in_bytes" : 7516336128 
        }, 
        "swap" : { 
          "total" : "30gb", 
          "total_in_bytes" : 32218378240 
        } 
      }, 
      "process" : { 
        "refresh_interval" : 1000, 
        "id" : 26188, 
        "max_file_descriptors" : 16384 
      } 
    }, 
    "node_hash2" : { 
      "name" : "node2", 
      "transport_address" : "transportip2", 
      "hostname" : "myhostip2", 
      "version" : "0.20.4", 
      "attributes" : { 
        "master" : "false" 
      }, 
      "os" : { 
        "refresh_interval" : 1000, 
        "available_processors" : 4, 
        "cpu" : { 
          "vendor" : "Intel", 
          "model" : "Xeon", 
          "mhz" : 2400, 
          "total_cores" : 4, 
          "total_sockets" : 4, 
          "cores_per_socket" : 32, 
          "cache_size" : "20kb", 
          "cache_size_in_bytes" : 20480 
        }, 
        "mem" : { 
          "total" : "34.1gb", 
          "total_in_bytes" : 36700303360 
        }, 
        "swap" : { 
          "total" : "0b", 
          "total_in_bytes" : 0 
        } 
      }, 
      "process" : { 
        "refresh_interval" : 1000, 
        "id" : 24883, 
        "max_file_descriptors" : 16384 
      } 
    }, 
    "node_hash3" : { 
      "name" : "node3", 
      "transport_address" : "transportip3", 
      "hostname" : "myhostip3", 
      "version" : "0.20.4", 
      "attributes" : { 
        "master" : "false" 
      }, 
      "os" : { 
        "refresh_interval" : 1000, 
        "available_processors" : 4, 
        "cpu" : { 
          "vendor" : "Intel", 
          "model" : "Xeon", 
          "mhz" : 2666, 
          "total_cores" : 4, 
          "total_sockets" : 4, 
          "cores_per_socket" : 16, 
          "cache_size" : "8kb", 
          "cache_size_in_bytes" : 8192 
        }, 
        "mem" : { 
          "total" : "34.1gb", 
          "total_in_bytes" : 36700303360 
        }, 
        "swap" : { 
          "total" : "0b", 
          "total_in_bytes" : 0 
        } 
      }, 
      "process" : { 
        "refresh_interval" : 1000, 
        "id" : 25328, 
        "max_file_descriptors" : 16384 
      } 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: @Vamshi Krishna: if you can help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082825/elasticsearch-log-file-huge-size-performance-degradation

Comment: This is not a warning. It's an error. You failed to open a file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How to increase the maximum number of allowed open files depends slightly on your linux distribution.  Here are some instructions for ubuntu and centos:

http://posidev.com/blog/2009/06/04/set-ulimit-parameters-on-ubuntu/
http://pro.benjaminste.in/post/318453669/increase-the-number-of-file-descriptors-on-centos-and

The elasticsearch documentation recommends setting the maximum file limit to 32k or 64k.   Since you are at 16k and are already hitting a limit, I'd probably set it higher; something like 128k. See: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation/

After upping the number of open files and restarting elasticsearch you will want to verify that it worked by re-running the curl command you mentioned:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes?os=true&process=true&pretty=true'
```

As you add more indices (along with more documents), you will also see the number of files elasticsearch keeps track of increase.  If you notice performance degradation with all of the indicies and documents, you can try adding a new node to your cluster: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/configuration/ - since you already have a sharded, replicated configuration, this should be a relatively painless process.

Comment: Hi @Dan Noble thanks for the info. My ulimit is already set to 65535. How come elasticsearch is taking only 16384? Do I need to change in setting in the config file to get the ulimit set by OS...?

Comment: Oops... sorry I have accepted the answer. But forgot to mention the same. Yes, I had to change the same at OS level to get the updated limit. Your comment helped a lot. Thanks @Dan

Comment: Hi, I met the same problem but I can't find where to set the file limit in elasticsearch.in.sh or elasticsearch.yml. Can you tell me how to set the limit of file ?

Comment: @DanNoble: Nice!! if you can help here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082825/elasticsearch-log-file-huge-size-performance-degradation

Answer (score 3):

1. Stop ElasticSearch. if you start from command like
   (bin/elasticsearch) then please specific this to set up heap while
   starting. For ex, I use a 16GB box so my command is

   a. **bin/elasticsearch -Xmx8g -Xms8g**

   b. Go to config (elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml) and ensure that

   **bootstrap.mlockall: true**

   c. Increase **ulimits -Hn** and **ulimits -Sn** to **more than 200000**
2. If you start as a service, then do the following

   a. export ES_HEAP_SIZE=10g
   b. Go to config (/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml) and ensure that

   **bootstrap.mlockall: true**
   c. Increase **ulimits -Hn** and **ulimits -Sn** to **more than 200000**

*Make sure that the size you enter is not more than 50% of the heap whether you start it as a service or from command line*

Answer (score 2):

Note that changing ulimits via `/etc/security/limits.conf` won't have any effect if elasticsearch is a `systemd` service.

To [increase the elasticsearch limit under systemd](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setting-system-settings.html#systemd) create a file `/etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service.d/override.conf` with the following content:

> [Service]
>   LimitNOFILE=infinity

Then run `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart elasticsearch`.

Comment: How do I do if using ES inside docker?