# How can I handle a large amount of ElasticSearch Index operations?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, firebase, ubuntu-14.04

I have developed a backend for a photo sharing app, with Node.js.
I use Firebase as the database. 
Here is a piece of the screenshots.
['Posts' section in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orI9p.png)

I am going to index the 'Posts' section to ElasticSearch( https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html).
Here is the indexing codes:

```js
// initialize our ElasticSearch API
var client = new ElasticClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 9200 });

// listen for changes to Firebase data
var fb = new Firebase('https://mydb.firebaseio.com/Posts');
fb.on('child_added',   createOrUpdateIndex);
fb.on('child_changed', createOrUpdateIndex);
fb.on('child_removed', removeIndex);
var index = 'firebase';
var type = 'post';
function createOrUpdateIndex(snap) {
   //var data = snap.val();
   //console.log(data);
   client.index(index, type, snap.val(), snap.key())
     .on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('indexed ', snap.key());
     })
     .on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); }).exec();
}

function removeIndex(snap) {
   client.deleteDocument(index, type, snap.key(), function(error, data) {
      if( error ) console.error('failed to delete', snap.key(), error);
      else console.log('deleted', snap.key());
   });
}
```

It is working well with hundreds of posts.
But with over 10K of Posts, it produces the errors in the ElasticSearch log window, like below:

```js
[2016-04-07 16:15:32,851][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [Caretaker] [[firebase][1]] marking and sending shard failed due to [engine failure, reason [index]]
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/user/Downloads/elasticsearch-2.3.1/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/firebase/1/index/_a.fdt: Too many open files in system
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:91)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
 at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:430)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:172)
 at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:271)
 at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:224)
 at org.apache.lucene.store.FileSwitchDirectory.createOutput(FileSwitchDirectory.java:155)
 at org.apache.lucene.store.RateLimitedFSDirectory.createOutput(RateLimitedFSDirectory.java:40)
 at org.apache.lucene.store.FilterDirectory.createOutput(FilterDirectory.java:73)
 at org.apache.lucene.store.LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.createOutput(LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.java:44)
 at org.apache.lucene.store.TrackingDirectoryWrapper.createOutput(TrackingDirectoryWrapper.java:43)
 at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.<init>(CompressingStoredFieldsWriter.java:111)
 at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.fieldsWriter(CompressingStoredFieldsFormat.java:128)
 at org.apache.lucene.codecs.lucene50.Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.fieldsWriter(Lucene50StoredFieldsFormat.java:183)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.initStoredFieldsWriter(DefaultIndexingChain.java:81)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.startStoredFields(DefaultIndexingChain.java:279)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:316)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:234)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:450)
 at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1477)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.innerIndex(InternalEngine.java:541)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.InternalEngine.index(InternalEngine.java:457)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.index(IndexShard.java:601)
 at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.Engine$Index.execute(Engine.java:836)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:237)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:158)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:66)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:639)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:279)
 at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:271)
 at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
 at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
 at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have struggled for this error and now I see it is because of maximum number of opened files in the ElasticSearch module when a great number of 'child_added' events are triggered in a short time.
I think I need to cache the Index operations to avoid this error keeping the limit of opened files as the default value.
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too many open files warning from elasticsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903105/too-many-open-files-warning-from-elasticsearch)

Comment: I already know this answer, just wanted to know how to cache Index operations by keeping the limit of opened files.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a Semaphore to limit the number of running index action to a specified capacity. Look at my post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37456691/2733216

The code is not tested, but should work.

```
// initialize our ElasticSearch API
var client = new ElasticClient({ host: 'localhost', port: 9200 });

// listen for changes to Firebase data
var fb = new Firebase('https://mydb.firebaseio.com/Posts');
fb.on('child_added',   createOrUpdateIndex);
fb.on('child_changed', createOrUpdateIndex);
fb.on('child_removed', removeIndex);
var index = 'firebase';
var type = 'post';

// Create a semaphore of capacity 1
var semaphore = require ('semaphore');

function createOrUpdateIndex(snap) {
   semaphore.take(function () {
   //var data = snap.val();
   //console.log(data);
   client.index(index, type, snap.val(), snap.key())
     .on('data', function(data) {           
        semaphore.leave();
        console.log('indexed ', snap.key());
     })
     .on('error', function(err) {
         semaphore.leave();
         console.log(err);
     }).exec();
   });
}

function removeIndex(snap) {
   client.deleteDocument(index, type, snap.key(), function(error, data) {
      if( error ) console.error('failed to delete', snap.key(), error);
      else console.log('deleted', snap.key());
   });
}
```

Then following your system concurrency capacity, you may adjust 1 to x

Comment: Could you tell me that the all requests are handled? I'd like to know if the requests out of the capacity are ignored or handled.

Comment: Personally, I use flashlight and it worked almost 100%. To be sure you may retry indexing object that failed, because they may failed for another reason  that semaphore protect.